# Magento2: connection refused mageplaza email

Tags: magento2, email

I get every time in exception.log any issue:

```
Next Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException: Connection refused in /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/mageplaza/module-smtp/Mail/Transport.php:89
Stack trace:
#0 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Mageplaza\Smtp\Mail\Transport->sendMessage()
#1 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Mageplaza\Smtp\Mail\Transport\Interceptor->___callParent('sendMessage', Array)
#2 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Mageplaza\\Smtp\\...', 'sendMessage', Object(Mageplaza\Smtp\Mail\Transport\Interceptor), Array, 'disableSending')
#3 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Plugin/TransportInterfacePlugin.php(54): Mageplaza\Smtp\Mail\Transport\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#4 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Email\Model\Plugin\TransportInterfacePlugin->aroundSendMessage(Object(Mageplaza\Smtp\Mail\Transport\Interceptor), Object(Closure))
#5 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/var/generation/Mageplaza/Smtp/Mail/Transport/Interceptor.php(26): Mageplaza\Smtp\Mail\Transport\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendMessage', Array, Array)
#6 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/EmailNotification.php(239): Mageplaza\Smtp\Mail\Transport\Interceptor->sendMessage()
#7 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/EmailNotification.php(362): Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification->sendEmailTemplate(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer), 'customer/create...', 'customer/create...', Array, '10')
#8 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php(789): Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification->newAccount(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer), 'registered', NULL, '10')
#9 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php(749): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement->sendEmailConfirmation(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer), NULL)
#10 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Customer/Model/AccountManagement/Interceptor.php(141): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement->createAccountWithPasswordHash(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer), '292d1d3ef252bd6...', NULL)
#11 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php(674): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement\Interceptor->createAccountWithPasswordHash(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer), '292d1d3ef252bd6...', NULL)
#12 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Customer/Model/AccountManagement/Interceptor.php(128): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement->createAccount(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer), 'Sonicmaster1', NULL)
#13 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php(290): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement\Interceptor->createAccount(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer), 'Sonicmaster1', NULL)
#14 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost->execute()
#15 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#17 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Custome...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor), Array, 'contextPlugin')
#18 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/Context.php(106): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\Context->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Custome...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor), Array, 'customer-app-ac...')
#21 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(61): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Customer\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Custome...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor), Array, 'storeCheck')
#24 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/StoreCheck.php(44): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\StoreCheck->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Custome...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor), Array, 'customer_accoun...')
#27 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Plugin/Account.php(60): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Customer\Controller\Plugin\Account->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Custome...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor), Array, 'weee-app-action...')
#30 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-weee/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(112): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Weee\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Custome...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor), Array, 'tax-app-action-...')
#33 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(91): Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Tax\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#36 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#37 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#38 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#39 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'requestPreproce...')
#40 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#41 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#42 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#43 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#44 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#45 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#46 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#47 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#48 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#49 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#50 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#51 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#52 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#53 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#54 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#55 {main} [] []
```

Anyone help me how to solve ?

Comment: https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp/releases/tag/v1.0.5

Comment: Should I download and replace these files?

Comment: Yeah they have fixed above issues so you can replace the files